# OnTrimMemory, but no Garbage Collection on Android

Tags: android, memory-management, garbage-collection

In Android, I'm correctly getting onTrimMemory calls, and I react appropriately. I release saved UI elements and lower memory usage by 50% when the UI is hidden.

The problem I'm having is that the Android system isn't running the garbage collector after each onTrimMemory call. I can see this in logcat. So I'll get a few onTrimMemory(CRITICAL) calls, and then eventually my background process will be terminated. However, if I use Android Studio to manually initiate a GC, the app will then release 50% of its memory back to the system, greatly increasing the chances of its survival.

I could add some System.GC calls, but I'm at a loss as to how/why Android would keep telling me to release memory, but refuse to run the garbage collector. (I still need to test more devices, as I do wonder if this is a device specific issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use WeakReference for non critical resouces?

Comment: I do that. The problem is not a memory leak. The problem is the garbage collector isn't running despite the system knowing that memory is low. If the garbage collector doesn't run, WeakReference resources will not be cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue with a specific phone. I couldn't reproduce this on a Nexus device. My Nexus devices do a garbage collector pass after an onTrimMemory call in which I release objects.